# Forcing "Windows XP" style on a c# Form-Based Executable, even in Vista, 7 etc

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, themes, styles

I've written an Application using Visual Studio 2008, on a Windows XP machine.  All the styling of the Form looks perfect there.

However, when the Application is run on Windows 7 or Vista, it uses the default style of those OS's instead, and it messes up the way some things look.

I read that, at build time, embedding a Manifest in my code might "tell" Windows 7 that I want to use the form style (Classic Style) that I built the thing in no matter what OS I'm on.  But, it appears that this embedding is already being done by default (so that's not the solution for me).

Thanks for any thoughts!

Comment: In what way does it mess up the way it looks? The best thing would be to just make it work in Windows Vista and 7 too, instead of trying to make it look like in XP.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using windows forms or Wpf? If you're using windows forms, you could try removing the line "Application.EnableVisualStyles" from Program.cs

Answer (score 0):

In the Manifest file you will add the following code under the assembly tag

```
 <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <!-- A list of all Windows versions that this application is designed to work with. Windows will automatically select the most compatible environment.-->

      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/> <!-- for windows 7-->

    </application>
  </compatibility>

  <!-- Enable themes for Windows common controls and dialogs (Windows XP and later) -->
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
          type="win32"
          name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
          version="6.0.0.0"
          processorArchitecture="*"
          publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
          language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</asmv1:assembly>
```